# DbContextBuilder does not contain definition for UseSqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core

I'm new to UWP and I'm trying to set up my project to use SQLite database, I'm making use of the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite.

When I try to set up the database context, I keep getting this error.

> DbContextOptionsBuilder does not contain definition for UseSqlite and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type DBcontextoptionsbuilder could be found (are you using directive or assembly reference)

Here's my code

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BradamaInternationalSkill.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Entity Framework Database Context.
    /// </summary>
    public class PersonContext : DbContext
    {
        internal DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=People.db");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Make Id required.
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .Property(p => p.Id)
                .IsRequired();

            // Make Name required.
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .Property(p => p.Name)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the issue by uninstalling the Nuget package "Microsoft Entity Framework  Core" and installing "Entity.Framework.Core.Sqlite.Design". I don't know why it solved the issue but the error is gone, I'm happy and that's all that matters.

Comment: this should be the correct answer. You saved my day!

Comment: "EntityFramework.Core.Sqlite" also works, I like to take the more general dependencies so that nothing breaks in future updates.

Comment: I was having the same problem trying to Scaffold a class following the Raozer Pages official tutorial from Microsoft. I'm using Visual Studio for Mac on an M2 mac. In my case adding the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite did not solve the issue. I had to remove the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer package and then try to scaffold again, and this time it worked and added back the sqlserver reference. Not sure why it fails but there is something not working properly on .Net Framework on Visual Studio (probably on the former because it did not work through command line either).